# Python 3. Как получить список всех палиндромов строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
from itertools import permutations

def is_palindrome(s):
    return True if s==s[::-1] else False

def get_palindromes(charactersSet):
    list_of_perm = list(set([''.join(item) for item in permutations(charactersSet)]))
    return [item for item in list_of_perm if is_palindrome(item)]

get_palindromes("some_string")
```

Но он проходит только 3 теста:

```
# Test 1
get_palindromes("ababb")
>>> ["abbba", "babab"]

# Test 2
get_palindromes("a")
>>> ["a"]

# Test 3
get_palindromes("ab")
>>> []
```

**И остаются скрытые 2 теста, которые код не проходит**. Проверив свой код на строки подлиннее, я выяснил, что код компилируется довольно долго, что, возможно, превышает 4 сек по правилам. И думаю, что проблема в `list(set([''.join(item) for item in permutations('some_string')]))`, который хавает ресурсы, перебирая перестановки строки.

Какой алгоритм будет правильным?

Comment: Какое-то странное описание задания. В строке "ababb" два палиндрома - "aba" и "bab". Ни "abbba", ни "babab" в строку "ababb" не входят.

Comment: *Проверив свой код на строки подлиннее..* Какой длины строки Вы брали? Если Вы используете перестановки, то надо помнить, что `P(n) = n!`... В свою очередь где-то при `n > 8` интерпретатор начнет сходить с ума, что, судя по всему, и происходит

Comment: тут можно посчитать сколько есть каждой буквы и уже от етого отбиваться) если нужно вот тут решение https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-palindrome-permutations-of-a-string/

Comment: @Эникейщик Имеется в виду палиндромы такой же длины как сама строка, а не палиндромы из его подстрок

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

1. Считаете количество всех видов букв.
2. Если есть более одного вида букв, встречающихся нечётное количество раз, то палиндром не получится, возвращаем пустой список. Если есть только один вид букв, встречающихся нечетное количество раз, то одна буква этого вида всегда будет в центре, а без неё этих букв будет чётное количество. Если всех букв изначально чётное количество - то у нас палиндромы без центральной буквы.
3. После того, как мы выяснили центральную букву или поняли, что центральной буквы нет, всех букв осталось чётное количество. Мы делим все эти количества на два, и перебираем все перестановки из половины набора букв. Каждую перестановку приклеиваем слева к центральной букве (или к пустой строке, если центральной буквы нет), и зеркальное отображение этой перестановки приклеиваем справа.
4. PROFIT!!!

Это должно получится существенно быстрее вашего алгоритма.

Comment: Впринципе, да, логично. Спасибо!